# Remove menu in FragmentActivity when Add Fragment with new Menu

Tags: android-actionbar, fragment

I have FragmentActivity with option menu A in ActionBar, in this Activity, I added one Fragment and ActionBar change to new option menu B. But after add this fragment, both menu A and B show in ActionBar. How to remove menu A when Fragment is visible?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer right now.
Ex in FragmentActivity I have

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_page_menu, menu);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_main, true); // this line to show menu of Activity

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

With

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<group android:id="@+id/menu_group_main" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_grid"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_grid"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_grid"/>

</group>
```

And Fragment I will set

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_grid_thumb, menu);

    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_grid_thumb, true);//this line to show menu of Fragment
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.menu_group_main, false);// this line to hide menu of Activity
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

With

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<group android:id="@+id/menu_grid_thumb" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_frag_grid"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_grid"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_grid"/>

</group>
```

It runs very well